# Using proxies with net/http in GO

Tags: http, go, https, proxy

I'm trying to use proxies with the net/http package. My proxy is a rotating proxy with a Username, password, Proxy address and a port.
I tried setting it as an environment variable using `os.setEnv()` as well as adding it in my windows 10 env variables but turns out maybe windows  does not support user-pass authenticated proxies.
I tried the http transport method too but could not get it to work

```golang
func SetProxy() *http.Client {
    cfg := GetConfig()
    if cfg.UseProxy {
        proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://" + cfg.Proxy)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        myClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
        return myClient
    }
    return &http.Client{}
}
```

Please if someone could point me to a tutorial or some documentation to use proxies specifically proxies with user-pass auth!

note: I used this format everywhere: username:password@proxyaddress:port

Comment: The code looks fine to me. What do you observe when you run the code? Did you try to debug your code by printing the cfg variable?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging it by printing out the proxy. So if I enter a wrong proxy, my program crashes without an error so I know it does use it in some capacity. If I enter a correct proxy, the program works as intended but there is no way of me knowing if it's using the proxy except checking the data left on the proxy. And the data on the proxy didn't seem to move even on running thousands of requests.

Comment: Please, try to print the client.Transport.Proxy function; if it's not nil, call it. If Proxy is not nil and returns not nil *URL, then proxy IS used.

Comment: that is smart, I will try this out! thank you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a debug attempt, you can print the `client.Transport.Proxy` function; if it's not nil, call it and print what it returns. If `Proxy` is not `nil` and returns not `nil` `*URL`, then proxy IS used.

Comment: Yup! The proxies were working, some problem with my computer! thanks so much

Comment: @PhysicsPanda, you can accept the answer if you think it helped :)